# Unpacking parameter packs in template aliases

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, gcc4.9, template-aliases

I run into a problem with unpacking variadic templates into a template alias.

The following code works with Clang 3.4 and GCC 4.8 but fails with GCC 4.9:

```
template <typename T, typename...>
using front_type = T;

template <typename... Ts>
struct foo
{
  using front = front_type<Ts...>;
};
```

GCC 4.9 complains:

```
test.cc:7:37: error: pack expansion argument for non-pack parameter 'T' of alias template 'template<class T, class ...> using front_type = T'
       using front = front_type<Ts...>;
                                     ^
test.cc:1:15: note: declared here
     template <typename T, typename...>
               ^
```

There exists a filed GCC bug ([#59498](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59498)), but is this supposed to fail? Here is some context from the [C++ core language issue #1430, "pack expansion into fixed alias template parameter list"](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1430):

> Originally, a pack expansion could not expand into a fixed-length template parameter list, but this was changed in N2555. This works fine for most templates, but causes issues with alias templates.
>
> In most cases, an alias template is transparent; when it's used in a template we can just substitute in the dependent template arguments. But this doesn't work if the template-id uses a pack expansion for non-variadic parameters. For example:
>
> ```
>   template<class T, class U, class V>
>   struct S {};
>
>   template<class T, class V>
>   using A = S<T, int, V>;
>
>   template<class... Ts>
>   void foo(A<Ts...>);
> ```
>
> There is no way to express `A<Ts...>` in terms of `S`, so we need to hold onto the `A` until we have the `T`s to substitute in, and therefore it needs to be handled in mangling.
>
> Currently, EDG and Clang reject this testcase, complaining about too few template arguments for A. G++ did as well, but I thought that was a bug. However, on the ABI list John Spicer argued that it should be rejected.

Comment: Can you move `front_type` outside of `foo` - they seem to be not related?

Comment: Yeah, good point @PiotrNycz. (It doesn't fix it, though.)

Comment: I checked this modified code with gcc4.8 - looks it works.

Comment: "works with Clang 3.4" This is rejected by clang 3.5.0 however: `error: pack expansion used as argument for non-pack parameter of alias template`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was reported in gcc4.9 bugzilla:

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59498

Minimal code to reproduce

```
template <typename T, typename ...>
using alias = T;

template <typename ...T>
using variadic_alias = alias<T...>;

using Fail = variadic_alias<int>;

int main() { }
```

---

From the explanation from gcc folks - **it is not so obvious this is a real bug.**
This is still discussion held in gcc bugzilla and in DR 1430 (http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1430) - summary in now in the question above.

Comment: It's reported as a bug but looking at the comments this seems to be by design.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like this is supposed to fail? I edited the question with context from [#1430](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1430)

Comment: @MatthiasVallentin I missed your comment - I will remove the duplicated content from my answer.