# Pack expansion for alias template

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, template-aliases

It seems that a pack argument can be expanded **only** in the place of a pack parameter of an alias template. This is not true for a class or a function template:

```
template <class T, class... Args> struct x { using type = T; };

template <class T, class... Args> using x_t     = typename x<T, Args...>::type;
template <class... Args>          using x_fix_t = typename x<Args...>::type;

template <class... Args> auto f(Args...) -> void {
  typename x<Args...>::type v1; // OK
  x_t<Args...> v2; // Error
  x_fix_t<Args...> v3; // OK
}
```

simpler case:

```
template <class T, class U> using y_t = T;

template <class... Args> auto f(Args...) -> void {
  y_t<Args...> v4; // Error
}
```

The above code generates error (even if `f` is never instantiated) with both `c++11` and `c++14` in `g++ 4.9`, `g++ 5.1` and `clang 3.5`.

Why is this not permitted and what is the general rule? I see no reason to restrict this. It seems a very strange prohibition.

As for why not writing as `x_fix_t` with the first variant it is more clear that `x_t` has a mandatory first argument. (for instance that is the reason `f()` is not permitted). But this is not that important, the fix is easy. The question remains: Why?

gcc error:

```
error: pack expansion argument for non-pack parameter ‘T’ of
alias template ‘template<class T, class ... Args> using x_t = typename x::type’
```

clang error:

```
error: pack expansion used as argument for non-pack parameter of
alias template   x_t<Args...> v2;
```

Comment: The info here is relevant, I think: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24433658/4326278

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, MSVC 12 and 14 RC compile this with no diagnostics (aside from normal warnings for unreferenced variables) - "implementation variance", as they say.

Comment: Works OK in g++ 4.8.2.

Comment: ICC 13 accepts the code as well -- is there any Standardese someone can point at that says no?  Otherwise, this is a very good find -- a regression in not one, but *two* disparate implementations!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This compiles in GCC 4.8 but fails in GCC 4.9, which is evidence that it's related to CWG 1430 and [bug report #59498](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59498). The fix proposed by Roy Chrihfield is the exact same one as yours:

```
Rewriting the code to use a struct succeeds:

template <typename T, typename ...>
struct alias { using type = T; };

template <typename ...T>
using variadic_alias = typename alias<T...>::type;
```

Furthermore, Jason Merrill elaborates on why it should fail:

> Actually, no, this is very much a Core 1430 issue; there's no way to
> mangle variadic_alias<T...> without mentioning the name of an alias
> template in the mangling, and they're supposed to be entirely
> transparent.  This only works in 4.8 by accident because checking is
> disabled for the release.

No further discussion exists in the bug report, so we can turn to CWG 1430:

> Originally, a pack expansion could not expand into a fixed-length
> template parameter list, but this was changed in N2555. This works
> fine for most templates, but causes issues with alias templates.
>
> In most cases, an alias template is transparent; when it's used in a
> template we can just substitute in the dependent template arguments.
> But this doesn't work if the template-id uses a pack expansion for
> non-variadic parameters. For example:
>
> ```
> template<class T, class U, class V>
> struct S {};
>
> template<class T, class V>
> using A = S<T, int, V>;
>
> template<class... Ts>
> void foo(A<Ts...>);
> ```
>
> There is no way to express A<Ts...> in terms of S, so we need to hold
> onto the A until we have the Ts to substitute in, and therefore it
> needs to be handled in mangling.
>
> Currently, EDG and Clang reject this testcase, complaining about too
> few template arguments for A. G++ did as well, but I thought that was
> a bug. However, on the ABI list John Spicer argued that it should be
> rejected.
>
> (See also issue 1558.)
>
> **Notes from the October, 2012 meeting:**
>
> The consensus of CWG was that this usage should be prohibited,
> disallowing use of an alias template when a dependent argument can't
> simply be substituted directly into the type-id.
>
> **Additional note, April, 2013:**
>
> For another example, consider:
>
> ```
>   template<class... x> class list{};
>   template<class a, class... b> using tail=list<b...>;
>   template <class...T> void f(tail<T...>);
>
>   int main() {
>     f<int,int>({});
>   }
> ```
>
> There is implementation variance in the handling of this example.

In otherwords, this is an on-going issue without any resolution (AFAIC) in sight.

Answer (score 0):

It is an annoying inconvenience, but there is a workaround:

make the `using` template take a single `typename T`, and make the caller wrap the variadic arguments in a `types_t` container

```
template<typename... Ts> 
struct types_t{};
```

and then, from the `using` now accepting a `types_t`, delegate the work of unwrapping and using the variadic arguments in another metafunction