# Why doesn't sizeof... work with this alias template?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, sfinae

I want to limit a variadic function to a certain number of inputs - say, two. For that, this works fine in my environment (VS2017, C++17):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... T> 
auto f(T...) -> typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(T) == 2>::type {
    // no-op
}

int main() {
    // f(1); // should fail
    f(1,2);
    // f(1,2,3); // should fail
}
```

But if I introduce an alias template, it doesn't.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... T> 
using two_params = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(T) == 2>::type; 


template<typename... T> 
auto f(T...) -> two_params<T...> { // failed to specialize alias template

}

int main() {
    // f(1); // should fail
    f(1,2);
    // f(1,2,3); // should fail
}
```

Interestingly, if I change the condition to `1` *or* the actual desired number of inputs, the substitution is successful.

```
// This works, except that it permits a single argument even when it shouldn't.
// Both conditions ||'d together seems to be needed in the general case.
template<typename... T> 
using two_params = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(T) == 1 || sizeof...(T) == 2>::type;
```

It seems that `f(1,2)` generates two values of `sizeof...(T)`. What exactly is going on here?

Some references I've looked at:

- [sizeof...](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...)
- [alias template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)
- [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)
- [Pack expansion for alias template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707011/pack-expansion-for-alias-template) (similar problem)

Comment: @hvd the first code block, but instead using the alias-template-using version of `f` (`auto f(T...) -> two_params<T...>`).

Comment: @hvd I have made the second code block a MWE for compile failure. It seems that it compiles in gcc & clang but not MSVC.

Comment: You're right, I messed up when testing.

Comment: @lightningleaf Your second code block (using the alias of `enable_if<sizeof...(T) == 2>` works fine for me. Maybe I am mistaken?

Comment: @L.F. It work fine for me. CLang on darwin. Maybe a bug of VS2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonathan Emmett from Microsoft has just [confirmed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/296409/failed-to-specialize-alias-template.html?childToView=299940#comment-299940) that it's a compiler bug:

> Thanks for this report. I can confirm that this is a compiler bug with
>   alias templates and pack expansions. We are currently working on a
>   major set of fixes for alias specializations, and this work is
>   currently slated to be included in the VS 2017 15.9 release. I can
>   also confirm that this bug is fixed as part of this rework.

Comment: This bug has not been fixed in Visual Studio Community 2017 15.9.17