# std::conditional for variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I'm trying to write a version of `std::conditional` that works for templates instead of types (if I understood correctly, `std::conditional` will not work with templates out of the box ("type/value mismatch")), but my understanding of parameter packs is limited.

Anyways, here's what I did:

```c++
template<bool, template<class...> class X, template<class...> class Y>
struct conditional_template
{ template<class... Z> using type = X<Z...>; };

template<template<class...> class X, template<class...> class Y>
struct conditional_template<false, X, Y>
{ template<class... Z> using type = Y<Z...>; };
```

So far so good, let's test it.

```c++
template<class> struct As {};
template<class> struct Bs {};

template<class Ta> using A = std::conditional_t<true, As<Ta>, double>;
template<class Tb> using B = Bs<Tb>;

template<bool choose,
    template<class> class C = conditional_template<choose, A, B>::template type>
struct bla{};


int main()
{
  bla<false> i; // <-- compiles in gcc 9.3, but not in clang
  bla<true> j;  // <-- does not compile in either gcc or clang
}
```

So, what's going on with the second line not compiling? The error message is:

```
template.cpp:17:58: error: pack expansion argument for non-pack parameter 'Ta' of alias template 'template<class Ta> using A = std::conditional_t<true, As<Ta>, double>'
   17 | struct conditional_template { template<class... Z> using type = X<Z...>; };
      |                                                          ^~~~
```

I'm confused, it seems like gcc is unpacking `class... Z` to `Ta`, okay, but then it tries to unpack `Ta` again (which must fail), but only if used in a `std::conditional` oO

EDIT: here's a link to play with: https://wandbox.org/permlink/XJBjxUf2TLxaPyzq

Comment: FWIW, this version https://godbolt.org/z/Q4Eeom compiles in gcc, clang, icc and msvc. It looks like there is a problem with alias template compatibility with variadic template template parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707011/pack-expansion-for-alias-template